# My download function saves a file with fixed name

Tags: python, html, django, download

I'm using Django 1.8 with Python 3.6.
When I use my download function below, it saves the file with a name fixed to local download directory. But I really want to keep the original name.

I can change the browser to open a download manager, but I want to know how to fix this filename to the original one.

```
def download(request):
    path = "test.jpg" # Original filename that I intend to give.
    file_path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT,path)
    print("file_path :", file_path)
    if os.path.exists(file_path):
        readFile = open(file_path,"rb")
        response = HttpResponse(readFile.read())
        response['Content-Disposition'] ='attachment; filename'+os.path.basename(file_path)
        response['Content-type'] = 'image/jpg'    
        return response
```

When I download the file, it is autosaved with a name 'Download.jpg', which is the browser's default directory name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have missed the `=`in your `response['Content-Disposition']`.
This one should work as expected:

```py
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=' + os.path.basename(file_path)
```

Comment: I know comments are not for this kind of words, but thank got you are a lifesaver.